# archive_command configuration POSTGRESQL 10.4

Tags: postgresql

Currently I have the following configuration for use `archive_command` in postgresql

```
postgres=# show archive_command;  
archive_command  
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
rsync -a %p barman@barman:/backup/primary_postgres/incoming/%f`
```

In my Barman server I can see the WAL files but I want to know why this files are erased, 
I was waiting to have all the WAL files and then manually errase the WAL files for been able to recover in time (PITR) but I can see that the files are erased after some minutes

```
[root@barman incoming]# pwd
/backup/primary_postgres/incoming
[root@barman incoming]# ls -ltr
total 147456
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000F7
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000F8
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000F9
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FA
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FB
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FC
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FD
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FE
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FF
[root@barman incoming]# ls -ltr
total 98304
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FB
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FC
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FD
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FE
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:56 0000000100000759000000FF
-rw-------. 1 barman barman 16777216 Nov 20 11:57 000000010000075A00000000
```

Do you know why this behavior and how I can be able to keep more historical WAL files?

Regards

Comment: do you have some other process on the `barman` server?  Sounds like you are putting things there, but something else is consuming them

Comment: Hi @richyen I have another backup Policy for another postgres DB but this backup is working in another PATH File system, the question maybe is to know how to retain the WAL files in `incoming` directory for more time :(

Comment: Then I think what you ought to do is send your files to a location of your choice, and have a cronjob pull from it, putting files into the barman `incoming` folder

Answer (score 0):

This is what "barman" does.  Incoming WAL are put in "incoming".  Then barman validates and catalogs them and moves them from "incoming" to "wals".

Why are you sticking your nose into barman's business like this?  If you want your archive to be outside of barman's control, then don't put it under barman's control.  Having your own home-grown tools and "barman" both trying to manage your system at the same time will end in disaster.  Decide if you want to use barman, or not use barman.

Comment: Hi @jjanes  good point sorry I am new using Postgres,  I did not know about this,      
I have a question what happens if I decide to apply a Point In Time Recovery?  the size of the wal files in  "wal" directory is not 16KB when I wanted to recover using this archives the RECOVERY process told me that the size of the archive was incorrect